# how to make tables in latex

Tags: tabs, latex

i'm new to latex i'm trying to make the table in the figure below but i can't:

here is my code:

```
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|c|c|c|X|}
\hline
KDD & SEMMA & CRISP-DM 
\\\hline
--- &  --- & Business Understanding \\[3ex]\hline
Selection & Sample &\multirow{1}{*}{ Data Understanding}\\\hline

Preprocessing & Explore\\\hline
Transformation & Modify&\Data Preparation\\\hline
Data Mining & Model& Modeling\\\hline
Interpretation/Evaluation & Assess&Evaluation\\\hline
--- & ---& Deployment\\\hline
\caption{Tableaux comparatif
\cite{KDD3}.}
 \label{tab:1}
\end{xltabular}
\FloatBarrier
```

if someone can help me i will be very grateful

Comment: Have  a look at the `booktabs` package to see how to make professional looking tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the issue is with the "Data Understanding" cell. I didn't see anything else wrong, but please point out any other issues if I missed them.

I think what you want is a `\cline` command:

```
Selection & Sample &\multirow{2}{*}{Data Understanding}\\
\cline{1-2}
Preprocessing & Explore & \\\hline
```

Also, for future questions LaTeX questions, you may get a faster/better response on https://tex.stackexchange.com/